# Use Task Schedule to offset System Time

Tags: windows-xp, time, task-scheduler

I have a Windows XP computer which is not connected to the Internet or to a network. As per [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/536167/722192) it seems to be an issue with the CPU or power voltage. It is a cheap offbrand computer with no CMOS Battery. It is running Windows XP.

I noticed it slowing down the time approx. 1.5 minutes per week.
I would like to set up a scheduled task to run each week and get the current time and offset it by 1.5 minutes.

Can someone please advise me how to set this up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Create a new txt document call it Fix_Time.bat and strip off the .txt
2. Right click on the new file and click on Edit.
3. Put in the file:

   @ECHO OFF

   time 12:01:30
4. Click Start
5. Click Settings
6. Click Control Panel
7. Double click Scheduled Tasks
8. Right click -> New -> Scheduled Task
9. Name the task Fix_Time
10. Double click the task
11. Under Run click on Browse and browse to where you saved the Fix_Time.bat file.
12. Under Schedule set it for weekly at 12:00:00 PM on whatever day you want.

Comment: Thanks. Small mistake should be 12:01:30. Going to wait a day before marking as solved, in case someone has a different answer.

Comment: What is the computer is off when the task is scheduled to run? Just saying...

Comment: @TwistyImpersonator Computer is running a display screen and is always on, unless there is a power failure. I can adjust manually if that happens.